# must always reload captcha to create a new account

Tags: magento2, create, account

In my webshop https://www.agoshop.at when I want to create a new account at https://agoshop.at/customer/account/create/ I must first reload the captcha to create a new account otherwise I will get always the message captcha wrong.
Hope someone can help me there how I can solve this.
kindly regards

---

Here the content of the log file db7f7a12fa2603ee2a51f312f00031c2332a1165e7ae52cdaa1cc1dc2a75c3b3):

```
{"0":"Warning: file_put_contents(\/www\/agoshopat01\/www\/agoshop.at\/pub\/static\/frontend\/smart_media\/smart_media1\/de_DE\/css\/themes.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in \/www\/agoshopat01\/www\/agoshop.at\/vendor\/wikimedia\/less.php\/lessc.inc.php on line 177","1":"#1 file_put_contents('\/www\/agoshopat01...', '\/* Less Variable...') called at [vendor\/wikimedia\/less.php\/lessc.inc.php:177]\n#2 lessc->compileFile('\/www\/agoshopat01...', '\/www\/agoshopat01...') called at [app\/code\/Rokanthemes\/Themeoption\/Observer\/RefreshStyleObserver.php:58]\n#3 Rokanthemes\\Themeoption\\Observer\\RefreshStyleObserver->execute(&Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer#000000007005c5be000000001659ac65#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php:88]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(&Rokanthemes\\Themeoption\\Observer\\RefreshStyleObserver#000000007005c596000000001659ac65#, &Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer#000000007005c5be000000001659ac65#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php:74]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->dispatch(array('instance' => 'Rokanthemes\\Them...', 'name' => 'refreshstyle'), &Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer#000000007005c5be000000001659ac65#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Manager.php:66]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager->dispatch('layout_generate_...', array('full_action_name' => 'cms_index_index', 'layout' => &Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor#000000007005b032000000001659ac65#)) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/Event\/Manager\/Proxy.php:95]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager\\Proxy->dispatch('layout_generate_...', array('full_action_name' => 'cms_index_index', 'layout' => &Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor#000000007005b032000000001659ac65#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Builder.php:134]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Page\/Builder.php:55]\n#9 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Page\\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Builder.php:65]\n#10 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Builder->build() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout.php:257]\n#11 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->build() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout.php:882]\n#12 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->getBlock('page_content_hea...') called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php:414]\n#13 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_hea...') called at [vendor\/magento\/module-cms\/Helper\/Page.php:215]\n#14 Magento\\Cms\\Helper\\Page->prepareResultPage(&Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor#000000007005b610000000001659ac65#, 'home') called at [vendor\/magento\/module-cms\/Controller\/Index\/Index.php:74]\n#15 Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index->execute(NULL) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Cms\/Controller\/Index\/Index\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#16 Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php:108]\n#17 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#18 Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#19 Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#20 Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#), array(array('designLoader', 'customerNotifica...', 'catalog_app_acti...', 'tax-app-action-d...', 'weee-app-action-...', 'storeCheck', 'contextPlugin', 'customer-app-act...'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Cms\/Controller\/Index\/Index\/Interceptor.php:39]\n#21 Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:159]\n#22 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#, &Magento\\Cms\\Controller\\Index\\Index\\Interceptor#000000007005b610000000001659ac65#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:98]\n#23 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#24 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#25 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/App\/FrontController\/Plugin\/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]\n#26 Magento\\Store\\App\\FrontController\\Plugin\\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor#00000000700587cb000000001659ac65#, &Closure#0000000070058e7b000000001659ac65#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#27 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php:69]\n#28 Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor#00000000700587cb000000001659ac65#, &Closure#0000000070058e7b000000001659ac65#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#29 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#30 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#), array(array('mstCoreDispatch'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#31 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#00000000700594bc000000001659ac65#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:116]\n#32 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#33 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#34 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#000000007005956c000000001659ac65#) called at [index.php:39]\n","url":"\/","script_name":"\/index.php","report_id":"db7f7a12fa2603ee2a51f312f00031c2332a1165e7ae52cdaa1cc1dc2a75c3b3"}
```

Hope someone can still help me what I can do now.
kindly regards

Comment: Need to enable production mode using this command,  php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

Comment: When I do this I will get the following message:
Enabling maintenance mode
Disabling maintenance mode
Command returned non-zero exit code:
` -f /www/agoshop.at/bin/magento cache:flush`

When I will load my url agoshop.at I will get now the following message:

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: db7f7a12fa2603ee2a51f312f00031c2332a1165e7ae52cdaa1cc1dc2a75c3b3

Hope you can still help me

Comment: I run not the command bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer but now my website is completly destryed. May someone can still help me. kindly regards

Comment: in var/ report , please check this (db7f7a12fa2603ee2a51f312f00031c2332a1165e7ae52cdaa1cc1dc2a75c3b3) log file

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I insert the content of the log in my first post.

Comment: Do you still facing issue for captcha?

Answer (score 0):

1. Kindly run the following commands, to run the website properly first.

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
   ```